# postgres app gets only 10.0 on Mac (sierra). how do I lower that version?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I tried installing `brew install postgresql@9.6` but then 
`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`
 returned this `command not found: pg_ctl`

Has anyone installed 9.6 version of postgres without the app and successful started the service or is there a way to install 9.6 via the app. it seems to get me the latest `10.0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your $PATH after `brew install`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/bin:$PATH"
```

Moreover,

> For compilers to find postgresql@9.6 you may need to set:
>
> ```
>   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/lib"
>   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/include"
> ```
>
> For pkg-config to find postgresql@9.6 you may need to set:
>
> ```
>   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/lib/pkgconfig"
> ```